# how can i add from my webpage to my android app with out updating the apk everytime?

Tags: android, web

hi guys i am constantly updating my website and i want all the stuff i update to appear in my app. so i don't have to make a new ".apk" update every time i add new stuff to my website.

would i use some sort of site scraping method?

what i would like to do is as new stuff gets added to my website it automatically pushes it to my app in some way

could some one at least point me in the right direction as i have only just got my head round setting up my website. please be nice and if u don't think this is worded right I am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to organize all your resource data in a **REST** web services and both website and Android App to get data from **Web Services**. So the data will be kept in one place (one place to do the updates) and be viewed from different platforms in your case a Web site and an Android App. However this is a very general architectural solution.

Comment: where would i start with this could i use my website for the one place for all data as im currently deep in to making it so would be a problem starting again

Comment: Sure, depending on the techonogies that you are using on your website the exact techincal aproch can be diffrent.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a WebView to your application and point that to your website the application would always fetch the latest version. I think this would be a quick and easy option for you. Link to documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

This would though require an internet connection for the user every time they use the application.

Here is the guide to web view API's https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: The WebView can be a solution but from experience can also be the beginning of your worst nightmare. If the website is simple it will work but if it is complex you may spend a lot of time trying to debug and fix very strange behaviors. So if your webpage is complex you should consider other options.

Comment: A webview certainly comes with its pros and cons. To get a more stable experience it can be worth trying https://crosswalk-project.org/ By adding this you would know that everyone would use the same WebKit version.

Comment: i dont want to use webview i want it a bit like a news feed so if you pull down  it would update or something like that